# Is there a way to always load a page as a dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3. Every time I present the View Novo to users, I need open this View as a dialog.

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel(); 
            viewModel.listaRedes = new SwitchBLL().GetRedes();
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Novo()
        {
            return View(new Redes());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Novo(Redes model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Do something
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cadastrado com sucesso!");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Não foi possível cadastrar. Por favor, tente novamente!");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Index View

```
@model CW.ViewModel.Redes.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<button class="btnNovo" onclick="openDialog('Nova rede','Redes/Novo')">Novo</button>
<table class="listas" id="rowSwitches" style="width: 100%;">
    @foreach (var rede in Model.listaRedes)
    {<tr onclick="jqGetRede(@rede.rede_id)" title="Detalhes do Servidor @rede.rede_u_name" >
        <td>
            <img width="12" src="/Content/Master/edit-icon.png" alt="Editar" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">@rede.rede_u_name
        </td>
    </tr>}
</table>
```

Here's how I open the dialog **onclick="openDialog('Nova rede','Redes/Novo')"**.  It works fine when the View is open for the first time, but when it's the return of the HttpPost the page not open as a dialog. I tried to put the content of the View Novo into a div and use the function (document).ready to call the JQuery function dialog to always open it as a dialog, but not worked.

function openDialog

```
function openDialog(title, url) {
            $('.opened-dialogs').dialog("close");

            $('<div class="opened-dialogs">').html('loading...').dialog({
                position: ['center', 20],
                resizable: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function () {
                    $(this).load(url);

                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
                },

                title: title,
                minWidth: 600
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Novo View

```
@model CW.Models.Redes.Redes
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "")
    <div id="addNew">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Novo</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NomeServidor)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NomeServidor)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NomeServidor)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TipoServidor)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TipoServidor)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TipoServidor)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ServidorURL)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServidorURL)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ServidorURL)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there a way to every time i open this View, it automatically open as a dialog?
What I've been found on the web didn't help, any suggestion, please?

Comment: This is not so straightforward as you'd like. On the `[Post]Novo` action, you must return the `Index` view, because that's the view that renders the dialog. Then you must modify your `IndexViewModel` to have a property of type `Redes`. Finally, on the `Index` view, you must test if `Model.Redes` is not null and open the dialog with the according data (such as validation messages).

Comment: @AndreCalil I will need to call that View from other Views than just the Index. If in the HttpPost I put a return to the Index it will return to the Index View all the time, right? What happens if a need to call it from other view  than Index? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could pass the return view as a parameter, but things would get hairy. The easiest way, in that case, is to change the `[Post]Novo` action to return a `JsonResult` and work with it with javascript, on each calling page.

Comment: Nope. Do you need some help with that?

Comment: I found this article: http://www.mayanksrivastava.com/2012/02/showing-aspnet-mvc-30-views-and-posting.html. And it really helped me! Even in HttpPost my page returns as a dialog. Thank you so much for all your help I really appreciate it.